# Using TIMESTAMP() over the Neo4j REST API

Tags: stored-procedures, neo4j

I am working on an application where Neo4j data is being updated for multiple clients in realtime. The times on the different client machines may be different, so any timestamps need to be set by the Neo4j database itself.

What possibilities does the Neo4j REST API provide for running TIMESTAMP() locally and inserting it into a field?

I know that I can create a query like...

```
WITH TIMESTAMP() AS timestamp
MATCH (node)
WHERE id(node) = {id}
SET node.updatedAt = timestamp
  , node.property = "new value"
RETURN node
```

... and use a [transaction](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.5/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-begin-and-commit-a-transaction-in-one-request) to execute it on the remote server. But is this the only solution? Are there ways to use the [Node Properties](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.5/rest-api-node-properties.html) URI so that the database will create the appropriate values dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j REST API is very limited in this case. As you mentioned you can use Cypher REST endpoint and set that value manually.

Another option is to writer your own Neo4j Unmanaged Extension, which will use Transaction Event API. It's similar to stored-procedures.

Here is very good article how to write that Extension by using [GraphAware Framework](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework) - http://graphaware.com/neo4j/transactions/2014/07/11/neo4j-transaction-event-api.html

Also here is simple real-world example that kind of Extension - https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid